# Uniform policy only for male employees

Tags: professionalism, company-policy, gender, uniforms

In my company there is a uniform policy only for male employees, whereas female employees are there and not wearing uniforms. How can I convince my boss to implement a uniform policy for all employees, including women?

Comment: What industry / type of work is this company?

Comment: More important, where are you? In most countries this would not be legal. If you have a HR department ask them about it.

Comment: What job are the uniformed employees doing? What about the nonuniformed employees? It may well be a reasonable requirement of the job, such as customer facing vs none-customer facing, or possibly working with industrial equipment vs not, etc.

Comment: To what extent the uniform policy is? For example, every male employee has to wear the very same style of suits?

Comment: Is it a 'uniform policy' or a dress code? Women tend to have more fashion options that would fall under business wear. I'm going to try not to make assumptions but if for example the 'uniform' is a short sleeved polo shirt with a logo on it, some cultures might feel this isn't appropriate for a women to wear when working with men.

Answer (score 8):

The first step in challenging a policy is to understand it. Start by asking why there is a different policy for women than for men. There may be good reasons (different job requirements, availability of suitable uniforms, relative cost, industry expectations, holdovers from prior management, or preference expressed by employees in each group).

It is unclear what the basis of your objection is. If you don't like having to wear a uniform, then the fact that women are not required to wear them is an argument in your court for abolishing them for men. If you like wearing a uniform, then it shouldn't matter to you whether others are required to wear them or not, unless there is some reason that their lack of a uniform is impacting your work.

Sometimes the only reason we are objecting to something is that it just seems "unfair." I would suggest to you that unless this policy regarding women's dress is impacting your work, you might let go of the need for and expectation of "fairness."  Fairness is relative; nothing is ever absolutely fair or equal. In pushing for it over an issue that does not impact you, you risk alienating coworkers and creating a divide amongst staff. Asking for a change regarding your own dress requirements makes sense here; asking for a change regarding the dress requirements of others is likely to be seen as an overstep.

Comment: You make a really good point with complaining about fairness.